# Visual Studio find out what command is assigned to an hotkey

Tags: visual-studio, hotkeys

I've installed a Visual Studio plugin that redefines some hotkeys. I need to come back to the standard hotkeys of Visual Studio for some of them. I know that under Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard I can redefine the hotkeys, and I did it. The problem is that now it seems that my hotkey Ctrl-E, C has two command associated, the plugin one and the standard one. When I press that combination visual studio runs the plugin command and not the standard one.

The problem is that I don't know the plugin-command name so I can't dissociate it unless I go through all the command to see the associated hotkeys. Is there a way to discover commands associated to a specific hotkey?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can try to assign this shortcut to another command and then you will receive info that this shortuct is already used by [your command]:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The Keyboard Shortcut Extension can help.  It produces a text file with a block of entries listing all your current shortcuts like this:

```
<command shortcut="Ctrl+M, Ctrl+E" name="Edit.ExpandCurrentRegion" />
```

You can then search for the command in the exported file using the shortcut.

[Keyboard Shortcut Explorer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ce3b73c-2284-4b95-b61d-6de74aa8dfe6)