# Multiple commands on Keyboard Shortcut in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to have multiple commands on same Keyboard Shortcut in Visual studio?

like clicking `F7` caused two different commands at the same time, instead of only 1 command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [Visual Commander](https://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/) command that calls multiple VS commands and assign a shortcut to it, like this:

```
public void Run(EnvDTE80.DTE2 DTE, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package package) 
{
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Copy");
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.Paste");
}
```

Comment: How can I add this command shortcut:
Ctrl + k, Ctrl + k, Ctrl + m, Ctrl + l, Ctrl + m, Ctrl + l, Ctrl + k, Ctrl + n, Ctrl + k, Ctrl + k

Comment: @Mehdi You should look for command names assigned to these shortcuts. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13764306/visual-studio-find-out-what-command-is-assigned-to-an-hotkey