# Is there any way to use the same shortcut for two commands in visual studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, code-formatting, using-statement, using-directives

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and I want to press (`Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D`) and, then have my code formated and using directives sorted and remove unsued ones.

In summary, Pressing (`Ctrl + K, Ctrl + D`) executes these two commands:

```
Edit.RemoveAndSort 
Edit.FormatDocument
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55101593/multiple-commands-on-keyboard-shortcut-in-visual-studio

Comment: @SergeyVlasov Thanks! I would like it to be without having to add any extension just with visual studio settings, in fact I think that in vs2017 you can. But the visual commander seems an amazing alternative.